# Выборка записей из нескольких таблиц и группировка

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы

```
users, likes
```

Делаю запрос

```
SELECT u.role, COUNT( u.id ), COUNT( l.id )
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, id
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS l ON u.id = l.user_id
GROUP BY u.role
ORDER BY COUNT( u.id ) DESC
```

Получаю результат, формата

```
| role | COUNT( u.id ) | COUNT( l.id ) |
|--------------------------------------|
|  1   |       50      |      10       |
|--------------------------------------|
|  2   |       40      |      1        |
```

где не правильно подсчитывается количество l.id

т.е нужно получить, количество пользователей по ролям и количество лайков поставленные пользователями, которые относятся к этой роли.

Comment: `SELECT user_id, id FROM likes GROUP BY user_id` - это некорректный  запрос. Либо `id` должен быть в агрегирующей функции, либо не должно быть `GROUP BY`. Подумайте, чего вы хотели добиться этим подзапросом.

Comment: Прямо в подзапросе количество посчитайте, а во внешнем просуммируйте

Comment: А структуру таблиц показать?

Comment: @Regent спасибо за подсказку, попробую исправить

Comment: @mmNick на здоровье. В принципе, ответ вам уже дали. Я лишь призываю к тому, что надо оценивать что вы пишете и что хотите этим добиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с учетом пользователей, записей про которых нет в таблице `likes`:

```
SELECT u.role, COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) users, COUNT(l.id) likes
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN likes l ON u.id = l.user_id
GROUP BY u.role
```

[Пример в SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b67be/3).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.role, COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) users, COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) likes
FROM users u, likes l
WHERE u.id = l.user_id
GROUP BY u.role
```

?

Comment: одинаковые значения в двух столбцах и не верные, отличаются намного

Comment: Пардон... поправил.

Comment: Думаю, во втором `COUNT` `DISTINCT` излишен.

Comment: @Regent Может, и лишний. А может, id этот ни разу не первичный индекс, и там дублей немеряно. DDL-то автор зажал...

Comment: @Akina l.id посчитались верно, а вот значения u.id срезало

Comment: @Akina если там есть дубли по `id`, то и `DISTINCT` не спасёт. Вот в чём фокус. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc90d/1).

Comment: @Akina дублей нет. Во втором `DISTINCT`  убрал

Comment: @mmNick что значит "срезало"? ID пользователей неправильно посчитаны по ролям, или же просто не все пользователи участвуют в выборке, ибо не про всех есть записи в `likes`?

Comment: @Regent Да ID пользователей не правильно посчитаны по ролям

Comment: @mmNick если в выборке должны участвовать все пользователи, независимо от наличия о них записей в `likes`, то вместо текущего `INNER/CROSS JOIN` нужно использовать `LEFT JOIN`: `FROM users u
LEFT JOIN likes l ON u.id = l.user_id`. И `WHERE` нужно тогда убрать.

Comment: @Regent Получилось, спасибо большое! Я до этого выполнял подобный запрос, теперь понял в чем я ошибся! Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @mmNick на здоровье. Не забудьте принять этот ответ, когда в нём появится `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Regent лучше напишите свой вариант запроса в форме ответа, а не комментария, и пусть автор его пометит как принятый. Это будет правильнее.

Comment: @Akina хорошо, раз вы так считаете. Оформил отдельным ответом.